# how to define key_func for tf.Dataset.group_by_window

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a image dataset. I want to feed the dataset in batches or windows of "n" number of elements, chronologically. I also want to drop the windows which contain images from the same time period.

All of this information is contained in the filenames, and I want to use the group_by_window() method to group the data.

How do I write the key_func function? I have seen some examples, but they are very use case-specific, and deal mostly with numerical or text sequence data, so I have not been able to use that information.

Ultimately, I want to declare a key_func such that would take an unbatched dataset as input, groups them in groups of 3 as long as all 3 images share some common information contained in the filename.

I already have the bit that extracts the information from the filename using regex

---

My images have filenames like so: "2021-09-20T17_04_58-camera1.jpg"

They are placed in a keras-like directory structure:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

I have a Dataset object of unbatched training data. This data would be passed to the key_func in the group_by_window()

The expected output is a Dataset object of windows of "n" number of elements

This is the regex I use: `(?P<timestamp>^(.*?)(?=-))-(?P<cameraid>camera\d)\.jpg`

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AloneTogether sorry, example of what exactly?

Comment: @AloneTogether I'm not sure if that's relevant, but added